# Question involving triangular matrices and simple modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Find the simple modules of the algebra $A$, where  $A = \begin{equation*} \begin{pmatrix} K & 0\\ K & K \end{pmatrix} \end{equation*}$ and $K$ is a field

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

I was thinking about something involving direct sums, I know that $A = E_{1,1}K \oplus E_{2,1}K \oplus E_{2,2}K$, but I don't know how to continue... I guess the summands are the simple modules of $A$. Could you help me?

Comment: Are your modules left $A$-modules, right $A$-modules, or $A$ bimodules?

Comment: You can assume right $A-$modules.

Comment: With minor modifications, the duplicate explains.